# How to sum time in array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

i have an array. i want to sum all time in the array so it will result sum of all time in the array. :

```
//print_r($chart_average);
Array ( [0] => 00:20:00 [1] => 00:03:45 [2])
```

how to sum all the time in array above and show result like below. How to calculate all array?

total time : 00:23:45

my answer for my reference after this :

```
 foreach ($chart_average as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $all_seconds += $hour * 3600;
        $all_seconds += $minute * 60;
        $all_seconds += $second;

    }

   $total_minutes = floor($all_seconds/60);
   $seconds = $all_seconds % 60;
   $hours = floor($total_minutes / 60); 
   $minutes = $total_minutes % 60;

    // returns the time already formatted
    echo sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes,$seconds);
```

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format

Comment: yes.. but it only have minute

Comment: That's hours and minutes.

Comment: yes but mine already in array have H:M:ss .. i  use array_sum but not work

Comment: adapt that code on the function. use:   foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $seconds) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute; seconds += $minutes*60;
    }

Comment: better you answer the question then..>.<

Comment: $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
   $seconds = $seconds % 3600; / and the minutes.. /

    // returns the time already formatted
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

Comment: I'd like to answer, but then people will downvote my answer... if you think it's right then I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I think it's easy to figure out what follows from the code on the other post. :)

Comment: the code works but i have problems in second..

Comment: You can do it with modulus... Do $minutes = $second / 60; $seconds = $second % 60 (it was not 3600, sorry)

Comment: have the element with the total input seconds be 'second' so it's not the same as the second variable 'seconds' with the total seconds (counting from minutes and hours) ---- list($hour, $minute, $second)

Comment: I'll post the complete thing. :-/

Comment: yes it right .. but i have problems in echo  the below part in second...see my code: 
 foreach ($chart_average as $time)
 { 
 list($hour, $minute, $seconds) = explode(':', $time); 
$minutes += $hour * 60; 
$minutes += $minute; 
$seconds +=  $second % 60;
 } 

$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;
//$seconds -= $second % 60;
 echo sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$times = array();

$times[] = "12:59";
$times[] = "0:58";
$times[] = "0:02";

// pass the array to the function
echo AddPlayTime($times);

function AddPlayTime($times) {

    // loop throught all the times
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $all_seconds += $hour * 3600;
        $all_seconds += $minute * 60; $all_seconds += $second;

    }


    $total_minutes = floor($all_seconds/60); $seconds = $all_seconds % 60;  $hours = floor($total_minutes / 60); $minutes = $total_minutes % 60;

    // returns the time already formatted
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes,$seconds);
}
```

Comment: i got this : 01:103:45 ... suppose : 01:43:45

Comment: yes, sorry, I changed this line:  $total_minutes = floor($all_seconds/60); $seconds = $all_seconds % 60;  $hours = floor($total_minutes / 60); $minutes = %total_minutes % 60;

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313656/split-down-a-number-in-seconds-to-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: yes now your code right.. but have liltle error..%total_minutes % 60; suppose $total_minutes % 60;.. thanks ..

Comment: cool..... this will be my reference after this.. i will using this more to produce chart.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$time = "00:58:50";
$time2 = "00:02:30";

$secs = strtotime($time2) - strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time) + $secs);
// 01:01:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda ugly but it works

```
$a = array('00:20:00', '00:03:45');
$h = $m = $s = 0;
foreach ($a as $time) {
    $time = new \DateTime($time);
    $h += $time->format('H');
    $m += $time->format('i');
    $s += $time->format('s');
}

$interval = new DateInterval("PT{$h}H{$m}M{$s}S");
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: i got this : 01:103:45 ... suppose : 01:43:45

Comment: i get 00:23:45 so could you double check you commented in the right place??